# No such image: testcontainersofficial/ryuk:0.3.0

Tags: docker, testcontainers

I faced with issue of using testcontainer:

com.github.dockerjava.api.exception.NotFoundException: {"message":"No such image: testcontainersofficial/ryuk:0.3.0"}

I tried the following recommended steps:

1. docker pull quay.io/testcontainers/ryuk:0.2.3
2. Set version: "org.testcontainers" % "postgresql" % "1.15.3"
3. And: "com.dimafeng" %% "testcontainers-scala" % "0.38.8"
4. For Docker desktop switch off the option "Use gRPC FUSE for file sharing"

But without result

Comment: testcontainersofficial:0.3.0 is saved inside hub.docker repository.

Did you login with docker login?

Comment: Yes, I login with docker login before  docker pull

Comment: Are you sure that you don't have any other dependencies, which pull (maybe transitively) testcontainers-java library version less than 1.15.1?

Comment: yuppie-flu.  testcontainers-scala 0.40.10 helped me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please make sure you are using the latest Testcontainers version (`1.17.3` at the time of writing). There were some issues with changes in Docker Desktop's authentication mechanism, that could lead to issues when being authenticated and pulling public images. However, these are solved with `1.17.3`.

Since it seems you are using Testcontainers Scale I can't comment on particular issues with the Scala wrapper, but `0.40.9` should bring in the latest Testcontainers version as well.

Comment: Thank you! 0.40.9 version for Testcontainers Scale is a decision. + docker pull testcontainersofficial/ryuk:0.3.0.  Instead of docker pull quay.io/testcontainers/ryuk:0.2.3